# Delete duplicates if multiple fields follow conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I had a simple Excel task to do today that I figured i'd use some Python to clean up. This led me to pandas and numpy.This is what i'd like to know if possible:

I have these columns and about 5k rows:

First Name  | Last Name  | Email | Address | City

I want to remove duplicates that fall within Address & City BUT, not all rows have a EMail or a Last Name. So I want to look at the row and delete the row that doesn't contain a email address, keeping the one that does.

However, I have some duplicate rows that have perhaps the same Last Name but with no e-mail, so i'd want to make sure that I keep atleast one of those rows, or insert NAN or something into the email field so that atleast one of the rows gets kept.

I guess in pseudocode it'd be this:

```
1. if Last Name & Address & City is a duplicate & Email Address on both rows is blank
             insert a variable into one of the rows Email Address field
2. if Address & City is a duplicate, remove the row that does not have a e-mail address assigned to it.
```

I've gotten it to work by manually going in and doing step 1 which as you can guess, is not fun lol. So i'm wondering if it's possible to do it with Pandas at all.

Here is sample Data:

```
       df = pd.DataFrame({
            "First Name": ["Bob", "Ken", "Bobs Business", "Daniel", "Wendy", "Kyle"],
            "Last Name": ["Arnold", "Arnold", "", "Amigo", "Amigo", "Zecke"],
            "Email": ["", "", "Bb@bobsbusiness.com", "amigo@amigo.com",  "", "k@zecke.com"],
            "Address": ["123 Street", "123 Street", "123 Street", "5 Street", "5 Street", "5 Street"],
            "City": ["Boston", "Boston", "Boston", "Concord", "Concord", "Denver"]
        })
```

The output expected:

```
First Name Last Name Email                Address        City
Ken         Arnold                       123 Street    Boston
Bobs Business        bb@bobsbusiness.com 123 Street  Boston
Daniel      Amigo    amigo@amigo.com     5 Street      Concord
Kyle        Zecke    k@zecke.com         5 Street      Denver
```

Thank you for any help or pointing me in the right direction! :)

Comment: You might want to look at [pandas.DataFrame.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html). Also, your logic might be incomplete as the second rule might remove both rows.

Comment: I examined duplicated but I couldn't see a way to set it to some kind of AND condition i.e 

df.duplicated(subset(['Last Name"] AND ['Address'] AND ['City']

Comment: You can pass multiple columns as a list: `df.duplicated(subset=['Last Name', 'Address', 'City'])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should provide example data, so we can easily test code on your data.
I think you have to do 2 things:

- sort your data ([sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html))
- delete the duplicated lines ([drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html))

you have to check if you use None values or emtpy string, because they befave differently on sorting, maybe you have to change keep to "first".

```
import pandas as pd


def run():
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "First Name": ["John", "", "Jane", ""],
        "Last Name": ["Last1", "Last2", "Last3", "Last3"],
        "Email": ["", "Email2", None, "Email4"],
        "Address": ["Address1", "Address1", "Address2", "Address2"],
        "City": ["City1", "City1", "City2", "City2"]
    })

    print(df)
    print()

    df.sort_values(by=["Last Name", "Address", "City", "Email"], inplace=True)
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Last Name", "Address", "City"], keep="last", inplace=True)

    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

output:

```
      First Name Last Name                Email     Address     City
0            Bob    Arnold                       123 Street   Boston
1            Ken    Arnold                       123 Street   Boston
2  Bobs Business            Bb@bobsbusiness.com  123 Street   Boston
3         Daniel     Amigo      amigo@amigo.com    5 Street  Concord
4          Wendy     Amigo                         5 Street  Concord
5           Kyle     Zecke          k@zecke.com    5 Street   Denver

      First Name Last Name                Email     Address     City
2  Bobs Business            Bb@bobsbusiness.com  123 Street   Boston
3         Daniel     Amigo      amigo@amigo.com    5 Street  Concord
1            Ken    Arnold                       123 Street   Boston
5           Kyle     Zecke          k@zecke.com    5 Street   Denver
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot about the data. I added some in. Your example works though, thank you so much :)